# Why are the same 32-bit floats different in JavaScript and Rust?

Tags: javascript, rust, floating-point, precision

In JavaScript, `38_579_240_960` doesn't change when converted to a 32-bit float:

```js
console.log(new Float32Array([38_579_240_960])[0]); // 38579240960
```

But [in Rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23c856d7819b935600aa686c7e39d0f5), it gets rounded to `38579240000`.  Howcome?

```rust
fn main() {
     println!("{}", 38_579_240_960_f32);` // 38579240000
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is just the formatting of the number limiting the precision of the print out in Rust. Try `let z = [38_579_240_960_f32; 5]; println!("{}", z[1] as u64);`

Comment: I'm surprised the default formatter doesn't at least include all of the integer digits, huh. Doing `println!("{:.0}", x);` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `38,579,240,960` is able to be represented as an IEEE-754 32-bit floating point number exactly, the trailing `960` is not significant. The 24-bit mantissa can only express about `7` meaningful digits. The next representable values above and below are `38,579,245,056` and `38,579,236,864`. So the number `38,579,240,960` is the closest representable value in a range spanning in the tens-of-thousands.

So even if you add `1000` to the value, neither languages change their output:

```
38579240960
```

```
38579240000
```

So the difference is that JavaScript is printing out the exact value that is represented while Rust is only printing out the minimum digits to uniquely express it.

If you want the Rust output to look like JavaScript's, you can specify the precision like so ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa749b6c4a76e9fb246923a9356781ad)):

```rust
println!("{:.0}", 38579240960f32); // display all digits up until the decimal
```

```
38579240960
```

I wouldn't call either one *right* or *wrong* necessarily, however one advantage of Rust's default formatting is that you don't get a false sense of precision.

See also:

- [How do I print a Rust floating-point number with all available precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26576889/2189130)
- [Rust: Formatting a Float with a Minimum Number of Decimal Points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65947428/2189130)

Comment: Your answer says the the value **is** able to be represented exactly, but the explanation goes on to describe how it is **not** able to be represented exactly.

Comment: This is an incorrect statement of IEEE-754 floating-point. The IEEE-754 standard is clear: Each floating-point datum represents one number exactly or a NaN. The “trailing 960” **is** significant, it **is** used in arithmetic, and it **does** determine the results of operations with it. It is a mistake to think of floating-point numbers as approximations. They are exact. It is the **operations** that approximate real arithmetic; operations effectively round the ideal result to the nearest representable numbers…

Comment: … Understanding this is essential for designing, debugging, and proving floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you are absolutely right, the trailing `960` is still significant in terms of the mathematical representation. I don't know how to best put it in words that the it represents an exact value, but its an approximate value of what you might be trying to represent.

Answer (score 8):

Your code snippets are *not* equivalent. JS prints `f64`, and Rust prints `f32`.

JavaScript does not have a 32-bit float type. When you read an element out of `Float32Array` it is implicitly converted to 64-bit `double`, because this is the only way JS can see the value.

If you do the same in Rust, it prints the same value:

```rust
println!("{}", 38_579_240_960_f32 as f64);
// 38579240960
```